# Jmeter HTTP Get Request Reading only Last line from CSV

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to use HTTP get request and trying to read values from csv for get parameters,the script is running but it is reading  only last line from csv and it is not reading any other lines

Please suggest what needs to be changed

I checked the thread group and infinite loop is selected

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite hard to say what's wrong without seeing your CSV file and your [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) setup.

If you have CSV file which looks like:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

And CSV Data Set Config which looks like:

[image]

each thread will read next line on each iteration:

[image]

More information: [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG)